# Entity Framework 6.2 Code First errors

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have some issues with Entity framework 6.2. I change ef version and now I have a lot bug..

EF version: 6.2
Visual studio version: 15.5.2
.Net version: 4.7.1
OS: Windows 10 Pro 1709

1.`NotMapped` why not working any more with inheritance? My example class:

```
public class BaseClass {  
    public string MappedProp {get;set;}  
    public virtual string NotBeMappedProp {get;set;}  
}  

public class Test : BaseClass {  
     public string MappedProp {get;set;}  
     [NotMapped]  
     public override string NotBeMappedProp {get;set;}  
}
```

2. `add-migration` not found entity framework on project. But I installed it already. Besides, I deleted all packages folder. However still continue same exception.
3. I open clean project but suprise... I have a new proplem. My foreign keys thrown an exception.

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types x1 and x2. The principal end of this association must be
>   explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data
>   annotations.

My code part looking like that:

```
public class Student{
     .....
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public long? LocationId {get;set;}
     [ForeingKey("LocationId")]
     public Location Address {get;set;}
     ......
}
public class Location{
     public long Id {get;set;}
     ........
}
```

It is working with previous version.

4. I have no migration, I updated my database, check table but entity framework still said, there is an migration.

> the model backing the context has changed since the database was
>   created

Answer (score 0):

1. Try add abstract modifier to `BaseClass` definition. `NotMapped` attribute should be at the lowest level. If you need to map overridden property you should map it with `Column` attribute directly in inherited class.
2. Try run command Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.2.0 -Project {{EFProjectName}} to reinstall package and reference it correctly.
3. You better want to specify `ForeignKey` attribute in Address class and its `StudentId` property(or whatever you call it). It is one-to-zero-or-one relationship.
4. Information about migrations are stored in the database table __MigrationHistory along with compiled db model to speed things up(checking everytime if code suits database is time consuming) and that is the reason you get that error. You have different compiled model in your code and different stored in the migration history. You can create empty migration running command Add-Migration -Name ManualDbUpdate -IgnoreChanges to overcomes this, but you must be sure code model and database model are equal. If not you are going to get exceptions.

Comment: 1. I try but nothing change.  
2. Several time did it. However I have no solution yet.  
3. Is your advice to use fluent api?  
4. I am very sure everything equal because I delete whole database and nothing exist any more.

Comment: 1. Can you update your question with generated migration code? 2. Make sure you switch to project with migrations on Package Management Console. If you have migration in separate project you must pick it to run command in project context. 3. I like to use fluent configuration better as it is more readable and at one place. 4. You may point to different db than you want. Usually it is problem when you have db in full SQL server instance, but startup project is trying to use LocalDb.